# the application closes when I use combobox.modelo

Tags: qml

I'm desperate I can not find the answer anywhere

I wanted to put a picture but I could =(

Problem upgrade:

My idea was to make a dynamic combobox

I discovered that the problem happens when office a modelo_query several veses
and this added to a model of combobox

Comment: Which version of Qt? Can you also provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? If it was just `ComboBox`, it could have been a known bug (depending on your Qt version). If the problem occurs also with other views...that most probably your bug.

Comment: I used version 5.3 I think, 
update the code segment failed

in which WANT ventata I put that code gives me the error

not if there's another way to do this

I need the second combobox model dependiento the result of the first combobox been reloaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**this was the solution:**

Component.onDestruction:{

```
 tf_Inaccesobolidad.model = null;
 tf_Inaccesobolidad_hijo.model = null;
```

}